# Is there a suggested order to read the Convergence Event DC Comics

Tags: dc, suggested-order

In the [Convergence event](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Convergence_%28Event%29), there are many two part comics. These all revolve around the main nine part Convergence story.

Is there a suggested reading order for these two part issues?

Comment: I don't feel like sitting down and elaborating on it, but http://www.comicbookherald.com/reading-dc-comics/convergence-reading-order/ seems to have a fairly comprehensive treatment of it.